# Program should work, still there comes no output?

Tags: java

Here is the Code:

**Main Class**

```
package geoformen;


public class Geoformen {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double zufall;
        Geo[] geoformen = new Geo[2];

        for(int i=0;i>3;i++){
            zufall = Math.random();

            if (zufall > 0.5){
                geoformen[i] = new Kreis(2);
            } else {
                geoformen[i] = new Rechteck(10,20);
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i>3;i++){
            geoformen[i].printGeoformen();
        }

    }
}
```

**The Geo Class:**

```
package geoformen;


abstract class Geo {

    abstract void printGeoformen();
}
```

**The Kreis Class:**

```
package geoformen;

public class Kreis extends Geo {

    private double radius;

    public Kreis(double pr){
        radius = pr;
    }


    public void setRadius(double pr){
        radius = pr;
    }

    public double getRadius(){
        return(radius);
    }



    public void printGeoformen(){
        System.out.println("Zeichne einen Kreis mit Radius: " + getRadius());
    }
}
```

And the Rechteck Class:

```
package geoformen;


public class Rechteck extends Geo {

    private double breite;
    private double laenge;

    public Rechteck(double pB, double pL){
        breite = pB;
        laenge = pL;
    }

    public void setBreite(double pB){
        breite = pB;
    }

    public double getBreite(){
        return(breite);
    }

    public void setLaenge(double pL){
        laenge = pL;
    }

    public double getLaenge(){
        return(laenge);
    }

    public void printGeoformen(){
        System.out.println("Zeiche ein Rechteckt mit der Laenge von: " + getLaenge() + "cm und einer Breite von: " + getBreite() + "cm");
    }
}
```

After I ran it, it just does nothing. It should give me an output like "Zeiche ein Rechteckt mit der Laenge von 10 und einer Breite von 20"

Where is the error?

Comment: It would be quite useful to learn how to set breakpoints and debug yourself. Questions like these are unlikely to be helpful to anyone else (and that's why you're getting downvoted).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`for(int i=0;i>3;i++)` should be `for(int i=0;i<3;i++)` otherwise the loops are never executed. Hence your program does nothing.

You should also increase the size of your array `Geo[] geoformen = new Geo[3];` or you will have an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception when accessing `geformen[i]` (arrays are 0 based indexed).